# Webpack Module Federation React Version issue in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webpack-module-federation

I have a react app that I need to run inside a NextJS host app and run on it's own.

In the NextJS example at https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/nextjs-react there are notes that:

> NOTE: If version: '0' is omitted, you'll encounter an issue where a copy of react will be downloaded from the remoteEntry.

> NOTE: Another issue you may run into is an invalid hook call if you are federating a component that uses react hooks. This is directly related to multiple copies of react running at the same time. The above resolves this.

I have set up a remote app with ModuleFederationPlugin:

```
shared: {
  react: {
    singleton: true,
    requiredVersion: false,
    version: "0"
  },
  "react-dom": {
    singleton: true,
    requiredVersion: false,
    version: "0"
  }
}
```

This works when running inside a NextJS host. But when I run my federated app on its own, I get `TypeError: n.n(...)(...).createContext is not a function.` If I remove version: "0" then I get invalid hook call when run inside the NextJS host.

Is it possible to handle both cases, or have a fallback in case there is no react version present in shared scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had to add:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {     
    react: path.resolve("./node_modules/react")
  }
}
```